# Referenced WCF Service doesn't use app.config

Tags: c#, wcf

I coded a WCF service which is referenced in DLL.
After I added that sevice reference an app.config was automatically generated with the requried data.

The client is using the dll to communicate with the wcf service...nothing special.
But when I'm trying to create an object of the service reference..its crashing, saying that it wasn't able to find an endpoint adress.

I googled around and fixed it by passsing the the binding and adress to the service reference:

```
readonly BasicHttpBinding _binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
readonly EndpointAddress _address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:50309/CustomerService.svc");

using (CustomerServiceClient client = new CustomerServiceClient(_binding, _address))
{
    return client.GetActions(customerNumber);
}
```

I'm wondering now, why I have to pass those parameters, when those data is already in the automatically genrated app.config.
I deleted the content of the app.config...and it seems those data isnt't used anywhere.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

app config in the dll project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50309/CustomerService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService"
            contract="ServiceReference.ICustomerService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: please include your app.config. Also I assume that app.config is for your entry point .exe

Comment: Are you sure your dll doesn't use your client's app.config? Or are you talking about that dll's app.config?

Comment: If your dll is seemingly igoring the app.config, you are most likely using the wrong one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note the following: **DLLs can *not*  have their own `app.config`!**

If you want the DLL to use configuration values, create them normally using the Properties for the DLL project, but then **copy the settings section** from the DLL's `app.config` to the EXE's `app.config`. Also, you need to copy the respective `sectionGroup` entry.

The DLL will then use the settings from the application's `exe.config` file.

Example of an `app.config` for an EXE project that provides settings for both the application and a DLL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="ExeProject" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="DllProject" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <applicationSettings>
    <ExeProject>
      <setting name="..." serializeAs="String">
        <value>...</value>
      </setting>
    </ExeProject>

    <DllProject>
      <setting name="..." serializeAs="String">
        <value>...</value>
      </setting>
    </DllProject>

  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: ...or in the `Web.config` file if the "client" is a website.

Comment: mhh, sounds logically. I tried it, but without luck. My service reference still crashes when creating a service object without parameters..maybe my config file looks wrong though. I replaced the section names and applicationsettings members with the names of the dll and exe project..and copied the <system.serviceModel> section to the dll project section..something wrong?

Comment: The `<system.serviceModel>` section needs to be in the application's `app.config` on a global level. The `applicationSettings` section cannot contain a `serviceModel` section.

Comment: Got it working now...got additionally a typo in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your dll *cannot* run on its own, its needs an executable to be used from (whether it's a windows service, web service, a plain desktop application, etc.). Because of this, dlls use .config files of executables they are used from - this is why your dll seems to be ignoring its configuration.