# App.config not returning key

Tags: c#, app-config

Please assist. I have been searching for an answer and I just cant find the solution.

I have the following app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="File1" value="...\XML Files\File1.xml" />
    <add key="File2" value="...\XML Files\File2.xml" />
    <add key="File3" value="...\XML Files\File3.xml" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is my code:

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string location = appSettings["File1"];

if (location != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(location);
}
```

The issue is that my location keeps returning Null

Comment: What project are you working on? Console app or web app?

Is the code you posted above using a separate class library to your main asp.net/console library?

If you are and you have added an app.config to this library with the settings posted above then the ConfigurationManager is not reading the right file as this will look to the app.config/web.config file for your asp.net library.

Comment: Can you check the path of the app.config that is being used with this: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;`
I don't know if you are running the app directly or not.

Comment: I can't see any error and above code is working for me without `<startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>` in config since i have older version.

Comment: @user1010863, yes it is looking at my Web,config file and not the config in my library

Comment: How do I change it? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @YvonneDelport Of course not, why would you expect it to look at the app.config in your library? The default is to use the config file of the 'executable', which is web.config for web-apps, and app.config of the .exe for console/win-apps.

Comment: @Maarten, Sorry it is my first time working with it

Comment: Why don't you use the auto-generated property `Properties.Settings.Default.File1`? Why's everybody using the `ConfigurationManager` directly (and failing)? If this is a DLL, you need to copy the settings and all other required entries from the DLL's app.config to your application's app.config/web.config file. Otherwise, the settings file will be ignored.

Comment: Did you ensure that the config file is placed correctly at the directory from which you're running the application? Is there actually a file called <app name>.exe.config in that directory?

Comment: @YvonneDelport Move the settings of your library app.config to the web-config

Comment: Thank you for the help. Moved the settings to the Web.config file. Now it is picking up my keys.

Comment: @YvonneDelport You should really stop using the `ConfigurationManager` directly, but use the auto-generated properties. They are typed and you won't be able to misspell the settings keys when accessing settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the settings from the DLL's app.config file to the web.config file. DLL config files are not read by the framework!

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677829/referenced-wcf-service-doesnt-use-app-config/15678310#15678310) shows you how to do that. The DLL will then be able to access its settings as you'd expect.

Also: Please stop using the configuration manager the way you do. This is error prone. Visual Studio will create a `Settings` class for you with properties for every setting you create in Visual Studio, so please use these as:

```
 string s = Properties.Settings.Default.StringSettingName;
```

And yes, this works for DLLs, too, if you copy the settings to the main config file.